# Trying to capture accelerometer axis

Tags: arrays, swift, accelerometer

When the button is pressed I'm trying to only capture the z data not the x and y. However, every time I try to add the .z to `myData.acceleration {self.readings.append(myData.acceleration)}` it wont let me. How would I be able to only capture the z data when the y hits a -39?

The error comes up saying:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'CMAcceleration'

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var Count: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var StartCount: UIButton!

    var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var count:String = "..."
    var counting:Bool = false
    var readings: [CMAcceleration] = []


    @IBAction func StartCount(_ sender: Any) {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to:OperationQueue.current!) {(data, error) in
            if let myData = data
            {
                if myData.acceleration.y < -39
                {
                    self.readings.append(myData.acceleration.z)
                }
                else
                {
                    self.Count.text = "GO!"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Might be a very basic quesstion but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your array to hold values of type `CMAcceleration` but you are trying to add just the `z` value which is a `Double`.

If all you want in the array are the `z` values, change the array declaration to be an array of `Double`.

```
var readings = [Double]()
```

Comment: One more question, based of my code would the array stop recieving the data once the y acceleration isnt < -39 ? in other words does my code just start the capturing of the data but never ends it